# unable to mount smb share in fedora 14 through nautilus connect to server

Tags: fedora, samba, nautilus

I'm unable to mount smb share on my university network. Trying through the nautilus connect to server dialog just brings the password dialog up repeatedly. I'm able to mount the share using mount.cifs as root, but it'd be great to mount it through nautilus as well.

More specifically, no matter how many times I try, I get the dialog telling me:

> Password required for share courses on courses.its.carleton.edu

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  You should be able to connect via nautilus on F14.  What fields are you providing in the "connect to server" dialog, and are you being prompted for a password?

Comment: I'm no longer having this problem, as they now have a different server.

But before, I was filling out the server, share, username, and domain  name and getting the password prompt repeatedly. I never had the problem with earlier versions of Fedora, and I don't have the problem with the new server. :/

Answer (score 1):

The `File>Connect to Server...` produces the window were I complete the fields as follows:

```
Server Type: Windows Share
Server: localhost
Share: sharename
Folder: somedir/anotherdir
User Name: myuserid
Domain Name: THEDOMAIN-NAME
```

I use `localhost` for the server after having invoked `ssh` at the command line:

```
sudo ssh myuserid@example.edu -L 445:samba.example:445 -L 139:samba.example:139
```

Where `samba.example` is the name behind the firewall.

Comment: I think the server is just smb/afp, no ssh.

> ssh: connect to host server.example.edu port 22: Connection refused